# Hide button on the page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am facing an issue in JQuery. The scenario is that I have a Delete button in Modal popup. When i click that button, confirmation popup opens. If I click on OK button, I want to disable the Delete Button. I have written some JQuery but that is not working for this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Mark To Seller Confirmation</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure? You will not be able to edit or delete this order any more. Continue?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="seller()">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script>
    var dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#tableId").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetAllPurchaseOrder",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "PurchaseID", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "SupplierID", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "SupplierName", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Currency", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "TotalAmount", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Date_Of_Purchase", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Due_Date", "width": "56px" },
                {
                    "data": "PurchaseID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="DeletePurchase" onclick="Delete(' + data + ')">Delete</button>'
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "PurchaseID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-success" id="ViewPurchase" onclick="Display(' + data + ')">View</button>'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });

    function getpurchase() {
        $.get("/Home/GetPurchasePartial", function (res) {
            $("#purchaseModalBody").html(res);
            $("#purchaseModal").modal('show');
        })
    }

    function geteditpurchase(PurchaseID) {
        $.get("/Home/GetEditPurchasePartial", { PurchaseID: PurchaseID }, function (res) {
            $("#EditpurchaseModalBody").html(res);
            $("#EditpurchaseModal").modal('show');
        })
    }

    function CreateOrUpdate() {
        var modal = $("#purchaseModal");
        var form = $('form[name="purchaseForm"]');

        let tableData = $('#detailsTable > tbody > tr');
        console.log(tableData);

        var tableDto = [];

        $.each(tableData, function (rindex, row) {
            console.log(row);
            debugger;
            let tmp = {};
            tmp.pid = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('pid');
            tmp.productName = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
            tmp.qty = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            tmp.price = $(row).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            tmp.amount = $(row).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
            tableDto.push(tmp);
            tmp = {};
        });


        var form = $('#purchaseForm');
        var purchaseDt = {};
        purchaseDt.supplierName = $('#Supplier_ID option:selected').text();
        purchaseDt.supplierID = $('#Supplier_ID option:selected').val();
        purchaseDt.currency = $('#Currency option:selected').text();
        purchaseDt.TotalAmount = $("#totalamount").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Of_Purchase = $("#datepicker").val();
        purchaseDt.Due_Date = $("#datepicker1").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Departed = $("#datepicker2").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Arrived = $("#datepicker3").val();
        purchaseDt.TotalQuantity = $("#totalquantity").val();
        purchaseDt.Packaging_Cost = $("#Packaging_Cost").val();
        purchaseDt.Inspection_Cost = $("#Inspection_Cost").val();
        purchaseDt.Freight_Cost = $("#Freight_Cost").val();
        purchaseDt.Other_Cost = $("#Other_Cost").val();
        purchaseDt.TotalOtherCost = $(".totalothercost").val();
        purchaseDt.TotalCost = $(".totalcost").val();

        $.post('/Home/CreateOrUpdatePurchase', {
            purchase: purchaseDt,
            tableListDto: tableDto
        }).done(function (result) {
            GetMessage(result.message);
        }).fail(function () {
            window.location.href = "";
        });

        form.validate();
        if (!form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post("/Home/CreateOrUpdatePurchase", data, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    modal.modal('hide');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Saved Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }

    function Update() {
        var modal = $("#EditpurchaseModal");
        var form = $('form[name="UpdatePurchaseForm"]');

        form.validate();
        if (!form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post("/Home/UpdatePurchase", data, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    modal.modal('hide');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Update Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }

    function Delete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure ?") == true) {
            $.get("/Home/DeletePurchase", { id: id }, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Deleted Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }

    function Display(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure ?") == true) {
            $.get("/Home/DisplayPurchase", { id: id }, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Update Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }

    function seller() {
        alert("Ankur");
        var dataTable1 = $("#tableId").DataTable();
        dataTable1.columns('delete').remove();
        var modal = $("#purchaseModal");
        var form = $('form[name="purchaseForm"]');
        let tableData = $('#detailsTable > tbody > tr');
        console.log(tableData);

        var tableDto = [];

        $.each(tableData, function (rindex, row) {
            debugger;
            console.log(row);
            let tmp = {};
            tmp.pid = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('pid');
            tmp.productName = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text());
            tmp.qty = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            tmp.price = $(row).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            tmp.amount = $(row).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
            tableDto.push(tmp);
            tmp = {};
        });


        var form = $('#purchaseForm');
        var purchaseDt = {};
        purchaseDt.purchaseID = $('#PurchaseID').val();
        purchaseDt.supplierName = $('#Supplier_ID option:selected').text();
        purchaseDt.supplierID = $('#Supplier_ID option:selected').val();
        purchaseDt.currency = $('#Currency option:selected').text();
        purchaseDt.amount = $(".totalamount").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Of_Purchase = $("#datepicker").val();
        purchaseDt.Due_Date = $("#datepicker1").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Departed = $("#datepicker2").val();
        purchaseDt.Date_Arrived = $("#datepicker3").val();
        purchaseDt.TotalQuantity = $("#totalquantity").val();

        $.post('/Home/MarkToSeller', {
            purchase: purchaseDt,
            tableListDto: tableDto
        }).done(function (result) {
        }).fail(function () {
            window.location.href = "";
        });

        form.validate();
        if (!form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post("/Home/MarkToSeller", data, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    modal.modal('hide');
                    $("#purchaseModal").modal('hide');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Saved Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }

        $("#DeletePurchase").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Here is the output that will be helpful to understand the scenario.
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0RQy.png)
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ns7N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the jquery `hide()` function for this:

```
$("#DeletePurchase").hide();
```

**Update for DataTables**

Button inside DataTables can be removed by its own functions. Do it in the following way:

```
var table = $('#myTableId').DataTable();
table.button( 'index' ).remove();
```

Here 'index' is the column index inside DataTable. In your case it would be, I think, 7.

Comment: Firstly, check whether your seller() function is working or not? Place alert() in first line of seller() function then execute.

Comment: Yes seller() function is working perfectly. Only button is not hide.

Comment: "columns": [
 {
                        "data": "PurchaseID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="DeletePurchase" onclick="Delete(' + data + ')">Delete</button>'
       }
]

Comment: I have used datatables in my project.

Comment: Getting error

Uncaught TypeError: dataTable.button is not a function
    at seller (Purchase_Order:436)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Purchase_Order:1)

Comment: Which DataTable is this, Jquery ?

Comment: i have updated whole script in my query. You can see there and help me in this.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.2/b-colvis-1.6.2/b-flash-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.1/fh-3.1.7/kt-2.5.2/r-2.2.5/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.2/sp-1.1.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: This link I am using for DataTable.